# Results always returning 0 and accessing classees

Tags: c++

I am having a couple problems with my code.

First off, with the code like it is, No matter what information I put in, It always returns 0, Any suggestions on where to fix this and how? I believe it has something to do with my Class Employee. How would I go about fixing this?

Second, How do I access the information in int total()? I need to access it for the last bit of code.

Also if you notice anything else that I can do to optimize my program, I welcome your suggestions. I am learning C++ as I go and will always be a Student.

```
// Datamax.cpp
// Created by Kennith Adkins

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
public:
string eName;
float eHours;
float eWage;
float ePay;
float eOvertimeHours;
float eOvertimePay;
float eTotalPay;
float eTotalBaseHours;
float eTotalSalary;
float eTotalOvertimeHours;

int Overtime ()
{
    if (eHours > 40)
    {
        eOvertimeHours = (eHours - 40);
        eOvertimePay = (eOvertimeHours * (eWage * 1.5));
        ePay = ((eHours - eOvertimeHours) * eWage);
        eTotalPay = ePay + eOvertimePay;
    }
    else
    {
        ePay = (eHours * eWage);
    }
}
int total()
{
    eTotalBaseHours = (employee1.eHours - employee1.eOvertimeHours) +   (employee2.eHours - employee2.eOvertimeHours) + (employee3.eHours -   employee3.eOvertimeHours);
    eTotalSalary = (employee1.eTotalPay + employee2.eTotalPay + employee3.eTotalPay);
    eTotalOvertimeHours = (employee1.eOvertimeHours + employee2.eOvertimeHours        + employee3.eOvertimeHours);
}
} employee1, employee2, employee3;

// Start the main program here
int main()
{
// Gretting
cout << "Welcome to the Employee Pay Center\n";

// Employee1 information
cout << "Enter the employee name: ";
cin >> employee1.eName;
cout << "Enter the hours worked: ";
cin >> employee1.eHours;
cout << "Enter his or her hourly wage: ";
cin >> employee1.eWage;
cout << endl; // Adding a blank line to space the information out

// Employee2 information
cout << "Enter the employee name: ";
cin >> employee2.eName;
cout << "Enter the hours worked: ";
cin >> employee2.eHours;
cout << "Enter his or her hourly wage: ";
cin >> employee2.eWage;
cout << endl; // Adding a blank line to space the information out

// Employee3 information
cout << "Enter the employee name: ";
cin >> employee3.eName;
cout << "Enter the hours worked: ";
cin >> employee3.eHours;
cout << "Enter his or her hourly wage: ";
cin >> employee3.eWage;
cout << endl; // Adding a blank line to space the information out

// Returning the information to the Employeer
cout << "Employe Name ............ = " << employee1.eName << "\n";
cout << "Base Pay................. = " << employee1.ePay << "\n";
cout << "Hours in Overtime........ = " << employee1.eOvertimeHours << "\n";
cout << "Overtime Pay Amount...... = " << employee1.eOvertimePay << "\n";
cout << "Total Pay................ = " << employee1.eTotalPay << "\n\n";

cout << "Employe Name ............ = " << employee2.eName << "\n";
cout << "Base Pay................. = " << employee2.ePay << "\n";
cout << "Hours in Overtime........ = " << employee2.eOvertimeHours << "\n";
cout << "Overtime Pay Amount...... = " << employee2.eOvertimePay << "\n";
cout << "Total Pay................ = " << employee2.eTotalPay << "\n\n";

cout << "Employe Name ............ = " << employee3.eName << "\n";
cout << "Base Pay................. = " << employee3.ePay << "\n";
cout << "Hours in Overtime........ = " << employee3.eOvertimeHours << "\n";
cout << "Overtime Pay Amount...... = " << employee3.eOvertimePay << "\n";
cout << "Total Pay................ = " << employee3.eTotalPay << "\n\n";

cout << "*******************************************************\n";
cout << "*****************EMPLOYEE SUMMARY DATA*****************\n";
cout << "*******************************************************\n";
cout << "** Total Employee Salaries............ " <<   "**\n";
cout << "** Total Employee Hours............... " <<   "**\n";
cout << "** Total Overtime Hours............... " <<   "**\n";
cout << "*******************************************************\n";
    cout << "*******************************************************\n";


return 0;
}
```

Hey Guys, Thanks for the help. I have most of it done now. It is displaying all the information. I am now just working on getting it to display the Employee Summary Data. I revamped my code to make it cleaner because I was trying every suggestion given to me as I learn best by hands on.

Comment: Your `Overtime()` and `total()` functions are declared as having an `int` return type but don't have `return` statements. Does this compile? You should turn up the compiler warning level.

Comment: @Linuxios When I run the program, I get the names returned to me but nothing else. I thought with the code cin >> employee1.eHours; I was declaring the information to put there.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yes my code does compile and it just tells me about a possible loss of data because of the conversion from double to float. How do I turn up the compiler warning level?

Comment: You are indeed doing this, but you are never telling the compiler to calculate overtime or totals so these variables contain junk and may show anything, including 0.

Comment: Setting the warning level varies depending on the compiler. If you are using `gcc` there are a lot of options, at a minimum I suggest you use `-Wall`. If you are using Visual C++ there is a `/W4` option in the in the project `C/C++ General` settings.

Comment: Im using Visual C++ Ill set that up after I figure the issues I am having right now out. I am working on initializing and calling my variables right now. I think I  have it figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what you get for using non-initialized variables. You have set no value to your class members, you can't expect the compiler to guess what is your employee's name or total pay.

You need to use the form:

`object name.member name = value`

Comment: I told you I was a student and still learning. Ill try this out right now and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: I did not meant this to be aggressive in any way. You have to have the right mindset when approaching programming problems. In this case, you need to make sure that everything you want your program to do is being coded. If you want to display something, make sure that you have at first initialized your variables and called the appropriate functions when needed.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, I took your advice and got most of my coding done. Anymore more suggestions would be awesome as I am still learning the ropes.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you should call the functions before outputting results that are supposed to be produced by these functions:

```
employee1.Overtime();
employee2.Overtime();
employee3.Overtime();
```

Comment: Thanks paritybit, this was helpful. Any other suggestions that you can give me would be awesome.

Comment: If you're a beginner to object oriented programming, I would recommend you to read about classes. This tutorial may be a good introduction for you: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/